# Django: How can I add a looked up field to ListView?

Tags: python, django

I have a model (Listing below) that contains information about ship sailings.  The ports for the sailings are given by the duple of xxxx_country and xxxx_port.

I list the sailings with a class ListingView based on ListView.  I want to pass the port name to the template rather than xxxx_country and xxxx_port, and I can get the name from a Port model.  Here's the code:

```
# from listing/models.py

class Listing(models.Model):
    # Port Codes - see https://www.worldnetlogistics.com/seaport-codes/
    orig_country = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    orig_port = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)
    dest_country = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    dest_port = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)


# from codes/models.py

class Port(models.Model):
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    location_code = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)
    name = models.TextField()


# from listing/views.py

class ListingView(ListView):
    model = Listing

    # need code here that looks up the port name by combination of country_code and location_code
    # one Port object will be returned
    orig_port_name = ?
    dest_port_name = ?

    template_name = 'listing/home.html'  # change from default template name
    ordering =['-ship_sailing']  # reordering the list in reverse order
    paginate_by = 16
```

What code do I need to put into the view so that I can pass the orrig_port_name and dest_port_name to the template?

Best regards...Paul

Comment: I think you need to remodel this with a `ForeignKey` instead. A Django model is about storing, retrieving, and aggregating data effectively. By using a `ForeignKey` Django's ORM can also aggregate more effectively: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a `ForeignKey` that refers to `Port` objects instead of writing the fields like `dest_country` and `dest_post` in the model. This results in *duplicated data*. Duplicated data is an antipattern since it makes data harder to maintain, store, retrieve, and aggregate.

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    # Port Codes - see https://www.worldnetlogistics.com/seaport-codes/
    orig = models.ForeignKey(
        'codes.Port',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='listings_as_orig'
    )
    dest = models.ForeignKey(
        'codes.Port',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='listings_as_dest'
    )
```

Then you can thus fetch the

```
class ListingView(ListView):
    model = Listing
    queryset = Listing.objects.select_related('orig', 'dest')
    template_name = 'listing/home.html'
    paginate_by = 16
```

In the template you then can for example list it in a table as:

```
<table>
  {% for object in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ object.orig.country_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ object.orig.location_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ object.orig.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ object.dest.country_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ object.dest.location_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ object.dest.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: To dot the i, close the </table> ;)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - Thanks.  That looks promising.  I entered the Listing Model changes and ran a makemigrations and migrate and got a prompt asking for a default value.  I added ```default=1``` to each ForeignKey instantiation.  I get results but always the first entry (default) in the Port model.  Don't I need to specify something that specifies the JOIN condition?  In SQL I would say ```JOIN ON listing.country_code=port.country_code, listing.port_code=port.location_code```.  Sorry if this sounds stupid - I'm a Django newbie.

Comment: @PaulOfford: no, the `.select_related(..)` will make the `JOIN`s, and select the data, but wrap that in `Port` objects that are attached to the `orig` and `dest` attributes of the the `Listing` object. So the Django ORM makes it look as if you fetched objects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - Thanks.  I get what you mean now.  I was looking at it from the wrong way.  What we are doing is storing a reference to the correct Port entry at the time we create each Listing entry - hence joining the tables.  That's better than what I had in mind.